# HTC sense disables bounce (and other stuff) in ListView\GridView, how to enable it?

Tags: android, android-listview, bounce

Im using a ListActivity with a listview

The problem is that for some reason, on an HTC device, the listview has no baounce

I Tried to do setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS) on the listview but it didn't help

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually no native Android support for the 'bouncing' lists when overscrolling. The Android way is to have a 'glow' appear as you try to overscroll which gets brighter and bigger the more you overscroll.

Some manufacturers add in the bouncing behaviour as part of their customised interface - for example Samsung do which is why you'll see it on their phones but not on HTCs.

Hope that clears that up for you!